# MYSQL INSERT with Foreach

Tags: php

When I want to add

```
data1 sum1
data2 sum2
```

to database,
what is actually happening :

```
data1 data1
sum1 sum1
data2 data2
sum2 sum2
```

My form element is;

```
<input id="alan_" name="alanlar[]" type="text" class="form-control">
<input id="miktar_" name="alanlar[]" type="text" class="form-control">
```

And PHP;

```
foreach ($_POST['alanlar'] as $key => $value) {

            $baglanti->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO ders (ders_adi, ders_miktar) VALUES ('%s','%s')", ($value),($value)));
            $eklenen_ders_id = $baglanti->insert_id;
```

Jquery Code :

```
var sayac = 1;
    $(function () {
        $('#ekle').click(function () {
            sayac += 1;
            $('#dersler tbody').append(
                '<tr><th><strong>Ders ' + sayac + '</strong></th><td><input id="alan_' + sayac + '" name="alanlar[]' + '" type="text" class="form-control" /></td><td><input id="miktar_' + sayac + '" name="alanlar[]' + '" type="text" class="form-control" /></td><td><a href="#" class="sil btn btn-danger">Sil</a></td></tr> ');
        });
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Your form only reads 2 values, yet you want to save 4 values in the database. Where do the other two values come from?

Comment: Add the code to your question, not as a comment

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you are taking both values to single array, hence you can not distinguish between them. Foreach is running twice for both values and you are inserting the same value for both columns.

To resolve, take different names for both values or define a different array key.

```
<input id="alan_" name="data[]" type="text" class="form-control">
<input id="miktar_" name="sum[]" type="text" class="form-control">
```

And then iterate one array and use the key in another as these both are text field there will not be a problem. Iterate like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value) {
    $baglanti->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO ders (data, sum) VALUES ('%s','%s')", ($value),($_POST['sum'][$key])));
    $eklenen_ders_id = $baglanti->insert_id;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: DB is now;
data1 sum1</br>
data2</br>
sum2</br>

Answer (score -3):

Setting up the form control names sensibly greatly enhanced the form data processing on the server:

HTML

```
<input name="alanlar[0][alan]" type="text" class="form-control">
<input name="alanlar[0][miktar]" type="text" class="form-control">
<input name="alanlar[1][alan]" type="text" class="form-control">
<input name="alanlar[1][miktar]" type="text" class="form-control">
<!-- etc. -->
```

PHP

```
foreach ($_POST['alanlar'] as $set) {
  $alan = $set['alan'];
  $miktar = $set['miktar'];
  // ...
}
```